# escape string (% character) in encodeURI in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encoding, escaping, uri

I have a problem where I need to preserve %2F in a URI string. However, encodeURI encodes % as %25 (as normal), so the whole string ends up being %252F instead of %2F. How can I escape this so the % doesn't get encoded. This is happening deep within a framework, so JS manipulation is not an option, it needs to be done via string escaping. I've tried using \ in a number of ways, none of it is working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you have control during the decode process, an `unescape()` before `decodeURI` would help.
This way, every double encoding is consistently handled.

For example:

> decodeURIComponent(unescape("http%253A%252F%252Fabcd.com"));

will return

> 'http://abcd.com'

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is that I can't use JS to manipulate the value at all. It all goes through a framework and the only chance I have of manipulating it is by changing the string itself. I've also tried adding JS functions into the string but it's treated as a string.